# Javascript events fire in wrong order?

Tags: javascript, events, timer, settimeout

Can someone explain to me why when running the program below alerts I get is always "aaa" followed by "bbb"? I would expect it to follow steps:

1. I start the program
2. program runs and gets to setTimeout line. It sets timer and this timer will be fired in 5 seconds from this very point in time (not when the program finishes). There is nothing put in the event queue just yet
3. then, before 5 seconds is passed I click the document. As program is busy and still running the loop it will put callback for this click event in the event queue. This is the only event in even queue at the moment (timer set earlier had not fired yet)
4. 5 seconds is past, loop probably is still running and timer we set with setTimeout fires. This puts timers callback "aaa()" into event queue as second event callback to be executed, right behind click event that is already in a queue.
5. So when program finishes I would expect it to alert "bbb" first as this event was fired first (click before 5 seconds), then followed by "aaa" (setTimeout event fire), I always get however "aaa" followed by "bbb", why is that?

Isn't event queue First in FIFO (First in first out)? Is it browser dependent? WHy is this happening?

```
function aaa() {
    alert("aaa");
}

setTimeout(aaa, 5000);

document.onclick = function () {
    alert("bbb");
}

for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

JSFiddle is here http://jsfiddle.net/sQvYG/1/

EDIT: Unless I'm missing something (possibly very embarassing) it looks like the code above does very similar thing to what John Resigs blog posts explains in details at http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/. Exactly the same thing, timer starts, click occurs and is added to the queue. Timer fires and is added to the queue. Execution ends and click handler is executed first and thats what I would expect. Anyone can shed some light on why this is not happening in the right order for me?

EDIT: thanks to bfavaretto  who delivered accepted answer and was kind enough to explain queues in details I came to understanding that there is no one, but multiple "task queues" where events are placed. So the 5 steps I initially described above are in fact these:

STEP 1. (this is the same) I start the program

STEP 2. (this is the same) program runs and gets to setTimeout line. It sets timer and this timer will be fired in 5 seconds from this very point in time (not when the program finishes). There is nothing put in the event queue just yet.

Also I believe at this point nothing is placed in tasks queue just yet as I found on mozilla dev page https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/EventLoop this:

*"Calling setTimeout will add a message to the queue after the time passed as second argument."*

I also verified this in Chrome and it seems that callback is added to tasks queue when its actually fired.

STEP 3. then, before 5 seconds is passed I click the document. As program is busy and still running the loop it will put callback for this click event in one of the task queues that browser provides for this sort of event (mouse click, ui task queue). This is the only event in this task queue at the moment. Other tasks queues e.g. for timeouts are empty at the moment.

STEP 4. 5 seconds is past, loop probably is still running and timer we set with `setTimeout` fires. This puts timers callback "aaa()" into task queue provided by a browser specifically for this sort of events (timeouts). So now we have one task queue dealing with user interactions and we have one callback in there waiting (the callback from our click earlier in point 3). And we have another task queue that deals with timeouts and we have one callback in there waiting as well. That's the one with `aaa()` method that just fired after 5 seconds.

STEP 5. So when program finishes we have two task queues with one callback each. Now even though click was put into its tasks queue first **there is no guarantee whatsoever that this task queue (which is user interaction or something that deals with mouse clicks) will be processed first. This totally depends on browser implementation** and that's what was giving me headaches until bfavaretto explained it in his answer.

So in this example I mentioned only two task queues, browser however might have others. When program runs and is busy each type of  event is placed in task queue for its type. After program finishes browser decides which tasks queue to process, grabs callback from there, executes, once finished grabs something from the same or another tasks ques and so on. So in fact there is no way of knowing which queue will be processed next. Tasks in each particular queue are always processed in order however.

Ooff.. this seems to make sense now, Resig's article gave me overall idea of how things are done but as it turned out there is much more to it and hopefully finally I understand it right.

Comment: what is this for for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
    console.log(i);
} without it the script works fine.

Comment: @YussufS: It's evidence of a misunderstanding of JS events, is what it is.  :P  Nothing happens UIwise until the script returns.

Comment: My original answer doesn't answer your updated question. I just added a new, separate answer about that. I decided not to delete my previous answer, as I believe it clarifies some misunderstandings from the first part of your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exact behavior depends on the user-agent. In Chrome, your fiddle alerts "aaa" first, but in Firefox it alerts "bbb" first (assuming in both cases that a mouse click is performed while the UI is blocked by the `for` loop, and that the timer expires before that loop is finished).

I believe Resig's article is the result of his observations of how web browsers (or maybe a particular web browser) behaved at the time it was written (back in 2008). It doesn't go into details regarding some behaviors, maybe because there was no clear specification at that time (I'm not sure about that). Take the following paragraph, which is key to your question (emphasis mine):

> After the initial block of JavaScript finishes executing the browser immediately asks the question:  What is waiting to be executed? In this case both a mouse click handler and a timer callback are waiting.  **The browser then picks one (the mouse click callback) and executes it immediately**. The timer will wait until the next possible time, in order to execute.

The article doesn't explain why the mouse click is picked first. Maybe Resig stated that based on how Firefox behaves. My intuition on the other hand is closer to what Chrome does: the timer callback was added to the queue first, so it fires first. Some of Resig's statements are vague, some are inaccurate; he says that timers and intervals "fire" and "execute" without defining what he means by these terms (here, for example: "while mouse click handler is executing the first interval callback executes"; "execute" seems to have two different meanings, i.e., execution of synchronous code, and a timer's timeout expiring).

<sup>EDIT

I just checked [Resig's book](http://www.manning.com/resig/). He incorporated a revised and expanded version of that article in the book, which deals with the concepts and terms in a more clear way. He also introduced extra warnings about some behaviors being browser-dependent. However he also introduced something (likely an error) that makes the whole thing still confusing; as of today (2013-09-20), there is nothing in the [errata](http://www.manning.com/resig/excerpt_errata.html) about that.</sup>

Thanks to your question I now realize that; I thought I had finally understood the inner workings of timers and the event loop when I read Resig's article for the first few times. But it's time to look for a more accurate answer, so let's turn to the HTML5 specification and see what it says.

I suggest you take a look on taking the [timers section](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/timers.html), but the key is found on the section on the [event loop and queued tasks](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/webappapis.html#event-loops):

> An event loop has one or more task queues. A task queue is an ordered list of tasks, which can be:
>
> **Events**
>   Asynchronously dispatching an Event object at a particular EventTarget object is a task.
>
> Note: Not all events are dispatched using the task queue, many are dispatched synchronously during other tasks.
>
> **Parsing**
>   The HTML parser tokenizing one or more bytes, and then processing any resulting tokens, is typically a task.
>
> **Callbacks**
>   Calling a callback asynchronously is a task.
>
> **Using a resource**
>   When an algorithm fetches a resource, if the fetching occurs asynchronously then the processing of the resource once some or all of the resource is available is a task.
>
> **Reacting to DOM manipulation**
>   Some elements have tasks that trigger in response to DOM manipulation, e.g. when that element is inserted into the document.
>
> When a user agent is to queue a task, it must add the given task to one of the task queues of the relevant event loop. All the tasks from one particular task source (e.g. the callbacks generated by timers, the events dispatched for mouse movements, the tasks queued for the parser) must always be added to the same task queue, but tasks from different task sources may be placed in different task queues.
>
> *For example, a user agent could have one task queue for mouse and key events (the user interaction task source), and another for everything else. The user agent could then give keyboard and mouse events preference over other tasks three quarters of the time, keeping the interface responsive but not starving other task queues, and never processing events from any one task source out of order.*

So, we have *tasks* that belong to one of many *task queues* (or *task sources*). Timer callbacks are added to one queue, and click events are added to a different queue. Each queue is ordered, but user-agents are free to decide how queues are prioritized in respect to each other. Note the last paragraph. It seems Firefox gives preference to the UI Events queue. Chrome seems to give preference to the a different task source, where timer callback tasks are.

Comment: That is an excellent answer and all seems to make sense to me now. I will update my question with EDIT and information you explained in your answer here, hopefully someone else will find it useful. Thanks once again, I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

> program runs and gets to setTimeout line. It sets timer and this timer will be fired in 5 seconds from this very point in time (not when the program finishes). There is nothing put in the event queue just yet

The timer callback is added to the queue immediately. It will be postponed if the event loop ticks before the 5000ms passed. This means the timer will take longer than 5 seconds if the `for` loop is not finished yet.

> then, before 5 seconds is passed I click the document.

This is flawed. If the loop is still running, the UI is blocked and your click doesn't have a chance to get registered before the first alert ("aaa").

> 5 seconds is past, loop probably is still running and timer we set with setTimeout fires.

Flawed too. We're still on the first tick of the event loop until the `for` loop is finished. The timer callback can't be fired until then.

Comment: wow so when the click occurs the event is not added to the queue just yet? It will be added AFTER JS execution finishes? When setTimeout timer fires however after 5 seconds, then even if JS script still runs inside of a loop this event will be added right away to the queue?

Comment: I'm not sure if the click goes into the queue before or after the timer callback fires. What I'm trying I to say is that all synchronous code must be finished before the event loop ticks. UI events are asynchronous like timers are.

Comment: thanks for that bfavaretto! What I struggle with however is how it fits in Resig's explanation. In Resig's diagram 1. program starts, 2. (program still runs) timer is set, 3. (program still runs) click occurs first, 4. (program still runs) timer fires, 5. program ends, 6. click callback is executed as this occurred in (3) before timer fired (4). sorry if I don't make sense here anymore :/ and thanks for your help so far

Comment: @spirytus: Resig's example didn't tie up the CPU for the whole time.  Since it set its timer and returned immediately, the browser would be free to handle click events.  The browser might not even *notice* a click til after the JS returns, and in your example it apparently doesn't.

Comment: hmm not sure why you saying "set its timer and returned immediately". In Resig's diagram in first blue block, when timer is set the program doesn't return immediately but runs (in a loop or not, doesn't matter) till 18ms. During this time click happens and event is fired isn't that right?

Comment: @cHao You might be interested in checking the separate answer I just added. Resig's article is indeed innacurate.

Comment: @spirytus: Oops.  I just looked at the code at the bottom, not the diagram.  As i look through the article, though, i don't see him actually say that either event does or doesn't have priority over the other; the browser just picked one, and that's the one he decided it would take for his example.